# Responsive website - slider content with images does not fit in mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, slider

I have a website http://www.vinjerac.com  which has an image slider.
The complete site is responsive, but the slider content does not fit the viewport in mobile devices and the website looks distorted.
[image: Website as seen on a simulator.]

Can you please suggest a solution for the same.

Thanks

Comment: First. Your link isn't working. Second, add relevant code to your question. Links will come to a time where they stop working and future users won't get a clue of your question.

Comment: Apologize for the incorrect link, however, adding the code, which references CSS files will be only part of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have a look at your site, and found you are using bootstrap for the responsiveness. And also a plugin for the slider.

Bootstrap is not designed to work with other plugins.

One workaround would be use a bootstrap slider which is also called carosel instead of the plugin that you are using you find the bootstrap carosel [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: However that isn't the solution to the current problem, but we did use that plugin, so I'll mark this as the answer.